# Are two square matrices having the same eigenvalues and the same eigenspaces equal matrices?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does possessing the same eigenvalues and the same eigenspaces imply the equality of the matrices? If yes, then is the converse of this implication also true? I mean if the answer is yes, then is having the same eigenvalues and the same eigenspaces only a sufficient condition for the equality of the square matrices or is it the necessary and sufficient condition?

Comment: Do you assume your matrices to be diagonalizable? If not, then consider matrices which do not have any eigenvalues.

Comment: No, I'm not assuming diagonalizable matrices. But allow me to state that I'm assuming square matrices over the field of complex numbers. So, there is no chance of matrices with no eigenvalues.

Comment: This is not true unless the matrices are diagonalizable. Take a careful look at matrices in Jordan normal form.

Comment: Do you mean equal or equivalent? That makes a difference..

Comment: I meant equal. The corresponding entries being equal.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yaun          Well, I don't really follow the role of Jordan normal forms regarding my question. The concern of my question are ordinary eigenvalues and eigenspaces and not the generalized ones. Can you please give an example of two non-diagonaliazble square matrices over the complex field that possess the same eigenvalues and eigenspaces but are not equal matrices?

Comment: I was also wondering the other day that whether my question containing the phrase "same eigenspaces" is a legit one? After all, eigenspaces are vector spaces in their own right. Talking about "same eigenspaces" is really talking about two vector spaces being the same. But as far as I know "being the same" for vector spaces is "being isomorphic". So, I have second thoughts about my question being an appropriate one. Changing the phrase "Same eigenspaces" to "Isomorphic eigenspaces" made me recall that every two similar matrices and not even necessarily diagonalizible ones satisfy the criteria.

Comment: "Same eigenspaces" makes sense as a statement about subspaces of a fixed vector space; it makes sense to ask whether two subspaces of a vector space are literally equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrices

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc} \lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} \lambda & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & \lambda & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & \lambda & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda \end{array} \right]$$

have the same eigenvalues and eigenspaces, but are different. They can be distinguished by their generalized eigenspaces.

Comment: Thank u so much. Now, everything became clear.

Answer (score -1):

This  would imply any diagonalisable matrix *is* diagonal, which is absurd, as similar matrices do have the same eigenvalues and the same eigenspaces.

Comment: This is not true if "same eigenspaces" is interpreted to mean literally the same subspaces of the underlying vector space.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: I'm sorry, but similar matrices are matrices of the same linear map in different bases. Will you say an eigenvector/eigenspace of a linear map depend on the basis?

Comment: Similar matrices have eigenspaces which are related by a change of coordinates; if you think of the eigenspaces as subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$ they are not literally identical, a change of coordinates changes the literal subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$ involved.

Comment: I think of eigenspaces as subspaces of a vector space on which an endomorphism induces a homothetic transformation. This is intrinsic and has different  representations as matrices, depending on the basis chosen.

Comment: Yes, all of that is fine, but it's not the question that was asked, which is about matrices having literally the same eigenvalues and literally the same eigenspaces.

Comment: Anyway,  I don't know what's an eigenspace of a matrix *per se*. It requires choosing a basis.

Comment: If $A$ is an $n \times n$ complex matrix, the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $A$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ consisting of all vectors $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $Av = \lambda v$. $A$ and $B$ have the same $\lambda$-eigenspace if $Av = \lambda v$ iff $Bv = \lambda v$.

Comment: But this corresponds to an implicit choice of the canonical basis.

Comment: Yes, of course. That's what it means to work with matrices as opposed to linear transformations.